# Function with 2 outputs

Tags: matlab

I have written the following code:

```
function [ z,a ] = complx( numb )
z=abs(numb);
a=angle(numb);

end
```

but I get back just z and not a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the function as followed:

> [z,a]=complx(numb)

If you call the function just:

complx(numb)

then it returns only the first output, z.